# Do we have to use a magnet in the compass?

Tags: magnetic-fields

In compass we use a magnet or magnetized metals to interact with the earth magnetic fields,
Can't we just use iron or any unmagnetized metal?

Answer (score 0):

Then we could not differentiate north from south.